# Fail to start tasks/services in Docker Swarm: hnsCall failed in Win32: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying the [Docker Get Started tutorial, Part 3 (Services)](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app). So the part where I need to init a swarm and deploy a stack, all my service status is rejected:

[image]

The full error (using --no-trunc) is:

> hnsCall failed in Win32: The parameter is incorrect. (0x57)

Here are the steps I am doing:

- Ensure my image is correct (the `docker run` works well, I accessed `localhost:4000` successfully). Then I stopped the container to make sure it does not interfere.
- When I init the swarm, it says I have multiple addresses, so I chose a random one (I tried with either of them, same result) using `--advertise-addr`.
- `docker stack deploy` works, but when I check the status with `docker service ps`, none of them are up. `localhost:4000` has no listener.
- Note: I switched Docker to a Windows container.

I am new to Docker and this is beyond me. Can anyone please suggest a solution/debug way?

Comment: Do you execute the `docker run` inside the windows container?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort sorry not sure what you mean by "inside". I run all the above commands from my real PC. And yes, it's a Windows, with Docker set to Windows container.

Comment: What do you mean by a docker container? A vm? Or are you running docker on your pc and then starting a windows container inside it where you run docker again?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain again: I am running a Windows PC (real one, no VM or anything). When Docker runs, there is an icon in the system tray, I use that to run the option "Switch to Windows container" (so now, Docker is running on Windows mode and the option now shows "Switch to Linux container")

Comment: Which system are you running on? I tried to reproduce this on my pc (windows 10) and it runs fine if I do the exact same thing you do

Comment: This is my full PC specs (from DxDiag): http://pasted.co/de0e3628 . I am running it on Windows.

Comment: Hmm that is almost the same as my specs, could you try it with swarm address 127.0.0.1? That is the advertized address i used

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I am able to init a swarm but still have the same problem... Maybe something with the network/HyperV? Note that my current Internet is wifi, not LAN (I do have a disconnected cable network card)

Comment: Ok, I tried using Linux container instead (still running on Windows, but didn't switch to Windows container). It works... That's weird. Will it affect my apps on Windows?

Comment: That depends, what is your use case why you wanted to use the windows container?

Comment: Not for now. It's just I am quite familiar with Windows environment (because I have never worked with Linux before), I thought it would prevent trouble if I run Windows container for now. My stack (.NET Core) supports Linux but I have never tried before.

Comment: I'm currently seeing this same issue. I documented my steps to reproduce and things tried under this Github issues

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40621#issuecomment-655701105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried everything but cannot get it to run on a Windows container so I switched to Linux container. The Get Started part 3 runs well.

Comment: But what if we want to run Windows containers?

Comment: It cannot the last time I tried. Have to accept that I guess.